# Typescript files in Angular's "prod" build artifact

Tags: angular, typescript, azure-devops

I have an Angular project that I build with this command (in Azure DevOps)

```
node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build \
    --project="my-app" --prod --build-optimizer --base-href="/MyApp/"
```

In the artifacts folder no Typescript file is found, and that's ok because the compiled Typescript files are transformed in minified JS files.

The problem is that when I deploy and use the application I can see the HTML and Typescript files in the "Sources" tab, "webpack://" folder. In general it seems that Chrome can access the project's files

[image]

This is a huge problem because the customers can see the actual source code.
Do you know how can it be? What's my mistake in the build process?

Thank you

Comment: The content in your picture is not the build output at all. Are you sure you are not on the dev server?

Comment: Are you including source maps in your build output for some reason?

Comment: @mamichels no, that's not the artifacts folder. That's the deployed application running in Chrome

Comment: @R.Richards where is the "source maps" configuration? I'm not that expert to even know what a source map is :)

Comment: per default the ng build cmd does not create source maps. It is definetly removed by appending `--sourceMap=false` to `ng build`

Comment: This may help you: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/debug-angular-apps-in-production-without-revealing-source-maps-ab4a235edd85

Comment: Thank you a lot guys. In the `ng build` doc (https://angular.io/cli/build) I found that by default `--sourceMap=true`. Moreover in my `angular.json` I have `"sourceMap": true`.

I will set it to false during the CI build with `ng build` in order to leave the current behaviour in the local build process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I premise that in my angular.json file I have the setting `"sourceMap": true` set.

A first solution is to run the `ng build` command with the `--sourceMap=false` flag. In fact, in the official  `ng build` documentation the `--sourceMap` is true by default.
The problem of this first solution is that I will not be able to perform the debug operations on the deployed application (for example in the test and QA environments).

Following [this](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/debug-angular-apps-in-production-without-revealing-source-maps-ab4a235edd85) link I was able to allow both the scenarios, that is hide the sourceMap in the deployed application but allow to perform the debug operations if needed.

This is what I did:

1. Set this configuration in my `angular.json`

   ```
   "sourceMap": {
       "hidden": true,
       "scripts": true,
       "styles": true
   },
   ```

   This way no sourceMap is automatically linked to the minified JS files and the `webpack://` folder if hidden.
2. In Google Chrome's dev tools, Sources tab, select the `main-HASH.js` file and in its code right click the background and select "Add source map". In the text box enter the sourceMap link (that is the minified JS path plus a ".map" suffix)
   [image]
   [image]

This will show the `webpack://` folder allowing to set breakpoints in the TS code

[image]